# Twitter bootstrap 2.1.1 Collapse not animating when Opening a collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple button to open/close a collapsible part of my website implemented in twitter bootstrap. I'd like to use the collapsible javascript plugin, but it doesn't seem to work just right: The folding animation happens "on close", but "on open" it's instantaneous.

Here's a jsFiddle demostrating the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/whUvL/2/

On my navigator (Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on mac) the first time the button is clicked, the h2 "pops in" instantaneously. Clicking the button again "folds" the h2 with a nice animation. Clicking again "shows it" very quickly.

**How can I have the animation work "when opening" as well as "when closing"? Should I add more html/css, or maybe change some js?**

Also, I've noticed that this happens with jquery 1.8.2 and the latest twitter boostrap. With jquery 1.7.2 and bootstrap 2.0.2 [it seems to work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/whUvL/1/). I'd like to use the latest of both if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem. It's [right there in the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse):

> - Requires the Transitions plugin to be included.

In my defense, I must say that that part was grayed out and was not very evident as a requirement.

Once I included the transitions module, the animations started working again:

http://jsfiddle.net/whUvL/4/

Kudos to @funzionpro, who put me on the right track - once I knew that including the complete set of javascripts it worked, the rest was easy to deduce.

(I will mark this answer as correct in two days, until then I must leave it open because SO's policies regarding auto-responses)

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work fine if you add bootstrap.js of 2.1.1

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whUvL/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to investigate this. It was not the complete solution, but it put me on the right track! You clearly deserve the +1.